# Microsoft SQL Server foreign key constraint conflict

Tags: sql-server

I got this error lately, and I'm so confused on how to solve it:

[image]

Comment: Please post the actual code and error message in the question and not an image.  In your case, the error message means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear, you are trying to assing a value to `course_id` but you have a `FK constraint` with the table `section`. So you need add that course_id first to `section` before update the table `takes`

Answer (score 0):

Please put the stuff you have in the image into the question. But the message explains what is wrong pretty clearly.  The field `course_id` is a foreign key pointing to a primary key (or unique index) in table `dbo.section`, and the value you are trying to to update it to is not in that table.